# What is differnce between Object and Function

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm confuse understanding Object and Function

```
Object instanceof Function //true
Function instanceof Object // true
Function.constructor instanceof Object.constructor // true
Function.constructor instanceof Object.constructor // true
```

why Object instanceof Function is not false ? all objects is instances of Object so how Object is instance of Function, and Object and Function inherit methods from each other like Object.bind() and bind method is written in Function.prototype, how Object inherit this bind method from Function.prototype and Object.getprototypeof(Object.prototype) is null.
I understand it like this all constructors include Object constructor inherit methods from Function constructor prototype property and all simple objects inherit methods from constructor prototype property like Person constructor prototype property and Object constructor prototype property. There is no searching for methods in case of simple objects in Function prototype property.

Comment: `Object` is a built-in constructor function for objects. It is therefore a function (an instance of `Function`). Functions are objects in JavaScript, it is therefore an object too (an instance of `Object`).

Comment: good answer i like that